# How can I get the description of an embed and send it into another channel in a async def on_reaction_add function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was tryng to make some poll command, that when it reaches a certain number of votes send the poll content to another channel, I have the problem sending the result to another channel:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_reaction_add(self,reaction, user):
    if reaction.count == 2 and reaction.emoji == "✅":
        await reaction.message.reply(f"Votacion Aceptada")
    elif reaction.count == 2 and reaction.emoji == "❌":
        await reaction.message.delete()
```

This works except the part that has the ✅ that I need to send the description of the embed that has been reacted to a channel by the ID, how can i do this? And if it's not too much to ask how can i check the channel before it enters the `if reaction.count == 2 and reaction.emoji == "✅":` part?

Comment: Are you looking for `await reaction.message.channel.send(...)`? Which channel do you want?

Comment: @EricJin One with the ID that is `poll_log=989260976027213834` poll log, but how do I get the description of the embed like i asked?

Comment: You could get it from the message if you have it: `message.embeds[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending your output to another channel is pretty easy.

First you provide the channel ID you want to pass the message to:

```
another_channel = bot.get_channel(int(CHANNEL_ID_HERE))
```

Then you send the message:

```
await another_channel.send(reaction.message.content)
```

Comment: That works with an embed?

Comment: @Zeninツ it does, why not. You can always define a new embed with the content you like and push it to another channel as above.

Comment: Okay, i don't know if it works cause i got an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` The code `polls_results = bot.get_channel(int(989260976027213834))
            await polls_results.send(reaction.message.content)`

Comment: @Zeninツ it's not a problem with embed, it's just a message like any other. It says it did not recognize `polls_results` as discord channel. You probably did not define the `bot` properly. I don't have the full information on how did you define `commands.Cog` so it's hard to help.

Comment: Okay I've solve it, it was `another_channel=self.bot.get_channel(int(989260976027213834))`  but now it outputs a error with the embed `discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message` this is a problem with the embed right?

Comment: exacltly as it says, you try to send an empty one. Try to print the `reaction.message.content` before sending it and look what's in there.

Comment: It has nothig but in the channel you can see the embed with the message  [Dicord Embed](https://imgur.com/a/9sH0K73)